Google Ads - Unavailable landing page ??? What?
Having a hard time with google ads.  I have 15 items in merchant center and want to promote them with a google shopping ad.  On day one, all 15 items were eligible for ads and I got several impressions and clicks. Slowly over the past week, 13 items became ineligible for the reasons of Unavailable mobile landing page and Unavailable desktop landing page.  Why would something like this happen?  They certainly are easily viewed on desktop and mobile. I'm not aware of my site being down at all. I've tested all the pages.  Any suggestions?  Anyone else have this problem?

Did you check the robots directives for those pages? They have to be readable (and, off the top of my head, I think) indexable by Google's bots. Did you also check that, not only are the pages actually loading in your browser, but that the URLs are returning correct 200 responses? Google may be hitting a 301 from the URL you are using and they might choose to not like it.

Hi, thank you.   I used a site called Redbot and it told me I'm getting a 302 Found - The Location header contains a relative URI.  I figured out what was causing it.  A cookie is set on this page, then the page is reloaded with PHP (to show that the cookie was set).  It was reloaded with - header('Location:'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  I guess that's the wrong way to do it.   is there a better way to reload a page after setting a cookie?

Have you contacted Google Support yet? Because this could be a temporary glitch in the system. In any case, make sure that the URLs in your feed are exactly the same as the ones your users are going to - no redirects or URL changes. Next, check to see if any of the URLs are blocked by a robots.txt file or have a noindex value that prevents Google from accessing them.
If everything is okay, then only support can help you.
